# First Order Logic - Axiom vs Formula

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In First Order Logic i just studied Axioms' Schemes, that are:

> An axiom schema is a sentential formula representing infinitely many
>   axioms. These axioms are obtained by replacing variables in the schema
>   by any formula.

The axioms obtained are the same thing of formulas (in First Order Logic) or are different things ?
If they are differents, how  i obtain formulas from axiom schemes or from axioms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For propositional logic we have:

*Language*: connectives and sentential *variables*: $p_1,p_2, \ldots$.

*Formulas* are expressione formed with variables and connectives according to the formation rules; e.g. $\lnot p_1, p_1 \to p_2$ are example of formulas of propostional calculus.

A *schema* is an expression of the meta-language where the (meta-)variables: $\varphi, \psi,\ldots$ stay for *formulas*.

An *axiom schema* is an expression of the meta-language, like:

> $\varphi \lor \lnot \varphi$,

and it must be read as a "recipe" to generate infinitely many axioms (called *instances* of the schema).

How ? Replacing uniformly the meta-variables with formulas of the language.

Thus, form the axiom schema: $\varphi \lor \lnot \varphi$ we can generate the *axioms*:

> $p_1 \lor \lnot p_1, p_2 \lor \lnot p_2, (p_1 \to p_2) \lor \lnot (p_1 \to p_2), \ldots$

The same for predicate calculus (with the obvious changes regarding the basic elements of the language and the formation rules).

An example of axiom schema can be $\forall x \alpha \to \alpha[t/x]$ and a corresponding instance is: $\forall x (x \ge 0) \to (1 \ge 0)$.

---

*In conclusiom*: axioms are expression of the (formal) language; axiom schema are expression of the meta-language.

Comment: If a want generate an axiom, i must put closed formulas in the system axiom ?

Comment: @Tantaros - not necessarily. The equality axiom is often written $x=x$, which is equivalent to: $\forall x (x=x)$.

Comment: Every axiom is a closed formula ?